# show dots in own-carousel when the window size is less than 768px?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, owl-carousel

I am making an owl carousel . 
I want when screen size is less than 768px, it shows dots below the carousel so that user knows its carousel here responsive

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the responsive option to your carousel, like de code below. Just add the breakpoint and the options that you want for this breakpoint up.

```
responsive : {
    // breakpoint from 0 up
    0 : {
        dots: true
    },
    // breakpoint from 768 up
    768 : {
        dots: false
    }
}
```

More examples at:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html